# Removing event listener with event reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, event-listener

I am trying to make a web page play drum sound audio on keypress of Q, W, E, R, and T. The audio is stored in a React state object:

```
    const [sounds, setSounds] = useState({
        loadState: false,
        Q : "",
        W : "",
        E : "", 
        R : "",
        T : ""
    })
```

and will be updated to one of several consts, representing different styles controlled by buttons shown later:

```
    function makeAudioObj(genre) {
        return ({
            loadState: true,
            Q : new Audio(`/audio/${genre}/${genre}_kick.wav`),
            W : new Audio(`/audio/${genre}/${genre}_snare.wav`),
            E : new Audio(`/audio/${genre}/${genre}_hat.wav`), 
            R : new Audio(`/audio/${genre}/${genre}_cymbal.wav`),
            T : new Audio(`/audio/${genre}/${genre}_misc.wav`)
        })
    }

    const rnbAudio = makeAudioObj('rnb');
    const hiphopAudio = makeAudioObj('hiphop');
    const jazzAudio = makeAudioObj('jazz');
    const electronicAudio = makeAudioObj('electronic');
```

The keypress functionality is added as:

```
    function pressKey(e) {
        let key = e.key.toUpperCase();
        if (sounds.loadState) {
            sounds[key].play();
        }
    }

    function setListener() {
        document.addEventListener('keypress', pressKey);
    }

    function resetListener() {
        document.removeEventListener('keypress', pressKey);
    }
```

Finally, this is packed into a function to be executed by buttons that handle style change:

```
    const [firstLoad, setFirstLoad] = useState(false) // necessary to prevent removal of EventListener before it exists
    function kitSelection(genre, event) {
        if (firstLoad) {
            resetListener();
        }
        setSounds(genre);
        setListener();
        if (!firstLoad) {
            setFirstLoad(true);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={e => kitSelection(rnbAudio, e)}>{'R&B'}</button>
            <button onClick={e => kitSelection(hiphopAudio, e)}>Hip-Hop</button>
            <button onClick={e => kitSelection(jazzAudio, e)}>Jazz</button>
            <button onClick={e => kitSelection(electronicAudio, e)}>Electronic</button>
        </div>
)
```

The issue is that removeEventListener isn't working, but not in a way consistent with other posts on this site I've found. I believe the issue has to do with the fact that `pressKey` references an event, which means it is trying to remove a different function than was set. However, putting those same setListener/resetListener functions into button form elsewhere on the page (e.g. a button that handles adding of EventListener and removing it) does work, despite referencing `pressKey` the same way. This is confusing me on what manner I am implementing this wrong. Additionally, I don't know how else a functionality like the one I'm after can be implemented *without* referencing an event, if that is indeed the problem.

Comment: Instead of adding onClick you can directly add onKeyDown prop. You don't have to add and remove event listeners then.

Comment: I don't think I understand. The onClick for those buttons is really to update the state object, and I don't want to attach that function to a keypress.

Comment: Try not to set the listener when you click on the button, keep the pressKey on onKeyDown

Comment: Oh wow, this works and seems like an intuitive solution. It only works when the element is focused so I threw onKeyDown={pressKey} on a wrapper <div> that covers the whole screen. I also had to include a catch to only try and play if the keys match Q, W, E, R, or T.
I'm going to leave the question open if there is a direct fix for the listeners, but thank you very much!